# Hibernate Naming Strategy is ignored

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence

I configured hibernate in my application through the persistence.xml which looks like:

```
<persistence-unit name="entityManager"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />   
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />       
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And through the EntityManagerUtil class that create EnityManagerFactory:

```
            Config config=CommonSettings.getInstance().config;
        Map<String, Object> configOverrides = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy","org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.dialect",config.hibernateConfig.dialect);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.show_sql", config.hibernateConfig.showSql);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", config.hibernateConfig.maxFetchDepth);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size",config.hibernateConfig.batchSize);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.connection.pool_size", config.hibernateConfig.poolSize);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", config.hibernateConfig.charSet);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding",config.hibernateConfig.characterEncoding);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", config.hibernateConfig.useUnicode);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", config.hibernateConfig.autocommit);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.connection.release_mode",config.hibernateConfig.releaseMode);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", config.hibernateConfig.useSecondLevelCache);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", config.hibernateConfig.useQueryCache);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries", config.hibernateConfig.useStructuredEntries);
        configOverrides.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class",config.hibernateConfig.factoryClass);

        configOverrides.put("packagesToScan", "org.prosolo.common.domainmodel");

        configOverrides.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver",config.mysqlConfig.jdbcDriver);
        configOverrides.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://"
                + host + ":" + port + "/" + database);
        configOverrides.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", user);
        configOverrides.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", password);
        try{

             emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("entityManager",
                configOverrides);

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried to configure naming strategy to ImprovedNamingStrategy in   persistence.xml and in config overrides. However, it doesn't work and hibernate generates new tables with CamelCase table names.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: I think mentioned links can be helpful to you.

"http://almaer.com/blog/hibernate-improvednamingstrategy and http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/implementing-a-custom-namingstrategy-with-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks. I've already found these links and many other, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Ok.. I think @VladMihalcea answer should help you more..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mapping looks just fine so I suspect the configuration is overridden by something in the bootstrap process.

Try adding a break-point in `EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.processProperties()` method at this code block:

```
else if ( AvailableSettings.NAMING_STRATEGY.equals( keyString ) ) {
    namingStrategy = strategySelector.resolveStrategy( NamingStrategy.class, entry.getValue() );
}
else if ( AvailableSettings.NAMING_STRATEGY_DELEGATOR.equals( keyString ) ) {
    namingStrategyDelegator = strategySelector.resolveStrategy( NamingStrategyDelegator.class, entry.getValue() );
}
```

and see if the configuration is available there.

Comment: Thanks Vlad for your suggestion. It brought me to the solution. I couldn't debug this as I don't reach this method. I have Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory which calls provider.createEntityManagerFactory. However, while I was trying to debug this,  I realized that I'm using Hibernate 4.3 in Maven submodule that contains hibernate entities and builds EntityManager and Hibernate 5.0 in project that uses EntityManager. Once I switched to version 4.3 in both projects, everything started to work fine. Thanks.